# How to write a custom MXNet layer with learned parameters

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, mxnet

I'm following the documentation in http://mxnet.io/how_to/new_op.html for how to define a new neural network layer in MXNet in python by subclassing the`mx.operator.CustomOp` class.  The example is of a loss layer that has no learned parameters.  So how do the learned parameters get into the `forward` and `backward` methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out.  Learned parameters are configured like any other input to the op.  They're configured in the `list_arguments` method.  From the [docs page on writing custom symbols](http://mxnet.io/how_to/new_op.html):

> Note that list arguments declares both input and parameter and we
>   recommend ordering them as `['input1', 'input2', ... , 'weight1', 'weight2', ...]`